# Помогите разобраться с архитектурой VIPER в UIKit

Tags: swift, uikit

Я собираюсь создать приложение с 4 UIViewController где на каждый VC будут загружаться данные с API. Навигация между ними с помощью таб бара.

**VIPER - View , Interactor , Presenter , Entity , Router.**

**View** - устанавливаю UI элементы.

**Interactor** - тут настраивиаю нетворкинг

**Presenter** - это VC тут устанавливаю констрейнты

**Entity** - это модель

**Router** - это мой таб бар

Я правильно понимаю архитектуру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presenter - это логика, которая управляет View (UI), т.е. View вызывает методы Presentera в ответ на действия пользователя (например), а Presenter обрабатывает их и изменяет View. Interactor не только нетворкинг, но и взаимодействие с Entity. Router отвечает за переходы между экранами. Но еще нужна логика, порождающая VIPER модуль, например, wireframe.

Comment: Спасибо! А констрейнты я устанавливаю в Presenter верно? Я вот это если честно не до конца понял. Где идет в VIPER именно их настройка.

Comment: Констрейнты относятся к UI, их нужно устанавливать во View.

Comment: Вот хорошая статья по архитектурам: https://habr.com/ru/company/badoo/blog/281162/

Comment: спасибо Вам! Буду лучше вникать со статье.